Reference request: functionals defined on diffusion processes
I have been studying on the textbook "A Second Course in Stochastic Processes" by Karlin and Taylor, 1975. Within the context of diffusion processes, the textbook shows a method to compute functionals of diffusion processes, such as:
$
\mathbb{P} \big( \{ \tau_b < \tau_a \} \mid \{ X(0) = x \} \big) \quad x \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R}
$
where $\forall z \in \mathbb{R} \quad \tau_z$ denotes the first hitting time of $z$.
Similarly:
$\mathbb{E} \big[ \int_{0}^T g(X(s))  d s | \{ X(0) = x \} \big] \quad T = \tau_a \wedge \tau_b ,\quad g \in \mathcal{C}_b$
In my textbook, the derivation is not so explicit. I believe that intermediate steps are implicit and I can't understand the derivations. I would like to find a textbook that addresses this kind of problems more explicitly, but I struggle to find one. Any reference would be more than appreciated.
